# Quando realizar testes e2e na sua aplicação?

Tags: front-end, testes, testes-automatizados, nightwatch, e2e

Estou iniciando na realização de testes e2e (end-to-end), especificamente em projetos [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) com [Spectron](https://github.com/electron/spectron) e [Nightwatch](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch).

Esta pergunta não terá código, pois minha dúvida neste caso não é com eles, estou conseguindo desenvolvê-los teoricamente bem.

Minha dúvida é para aqueles que possuem um maior conhecimento e experiência em testes no front-end, para se conseguir informar melhor as seguintes questões:

1. **Quando** realizar um teste no front-end em um módulo de sua aplicação?
2. O teste deve cobrir **todos os casos possíveis existentes** no módulo que está sendo testado? Como, por exemplo, clicar em todos os botões da tela, e realizar todos os fluxos possíveis que a tela fornece?

Pesquisei em alguns sites, e perguntei para diversas pessoas, e as informações passadas foram bem divergentes umas das outras.

Alguns falam que o teste no front-end deve cobrir apenas a parte mais importante do sistema, como, por exemplo, no caso de um e-commerce, deverá apenas existir testes automatizados no front-end para realizar uma compra no site, e os testes deverão apenas cobrir o "caminho feliz" (*happy paths*).

Para aqueles que possuam uma ideia sobre o assunto, opinião ou conhecimento, por favor ela será muito bem vinda.

**OBS:** Se aqui não for o local para este tipo de pergunta, pode informar nos comentários que apago ela sem problemas. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que no "**Quando**" realizar testes é algo relativo a necessidade do produto. Pensando em produtividade e garantia de testes em uma liberação, é interessante ter essa cobertura automatizada. Até colocando isso com relação a custo e benefício, automação vai te proporcionar maior escalabilidade e consistência no que é feito.

Agora relacionado ao índice de **cobertura** já vi profissionais estipulando percentual de cobertura em determinados produtos. Acredito que não seria uma boa prática, pensando em evolução. Penso que deve ser colocado nesse tópico o que é funcionalidade do teu produto, não só os caminhos ativos. Adversidade faz parte de todo produto em produção, nem sempre quem usa é um especialista.

Essas dúvidas são complicadas, mas é o que penso. Espero ter ajudado!